# Stripe ACH Deposit using Payment Sheet & Intent in React Native Expo

Tags: react-native, expo, stripe-payments, mobile-development

My app needs to take in deposits from customers from ACH bank deposits, I am able to successfully take deposits via Credit Card but not ACH bank deposits.

When I select ACH Bank deposits I do see the payment sheet for Bank Deposits but after following through all the steps I am re-directed to my expo app home screen and am kicked out of my app.

First I am using my API to create a payment intent, this is the function that creates the payment intent:

```
func CreatePaymentIntent(transactionId string, transactionInitiation openapi.TransactionInitiation, sc *client.API, db *gorm.DB) (openapi.PaymentIntentDetails, error) {

    // Get the user's email
    user := models.User{}
    // Retrieve the user by ID and populate the 'user' struct
    db.Where("id = ?", transactionInitiation.UserId).First(&user)

    amount := int64(transactionInitiation.Amount.Amount)

    // Initiate Payment Intent with Stripe
    custParams := &stripe.CustomerParams{
        Balance: &amount,
        Metadata: map[string]string{
            "purseId":         transactionInitiation.DestinationId,
            "userId":          transactionInitiation.UserId,
            "transactionId":   transactionId,
            "transactionType": string(transactionInitiation.TransactionType),
        },
    }

    logger.Logger.Info("Creating customer with params", zap.Any("params", custParams))

    c, _ := sc.Customers.New(custParams)

    ephKeyParams := &stripe.EphemeralKeyParams{
        Customer:      stripe.String(c.ID),
        StripeVersion: stripe.String("2020-08-27"),
    }
    ephKey, _ := sc.EphemeralKeys.New(ephKeyParams)

    payIntentParams := &stripe.PaymentIntentParams{
        Amount:       stripe.Int64(amount),
        Currency:     stripe.String(string(convertCurrency(transactionInitiation.Amount.Currency))),
        Customer:     stripe.String(c.ID),
        ReceiptEmail: &user.Email.String,
        AutomaticPaymentMethods: &stripe.PaymentIntentAutomaticPaymentMethodsParams{
            Enabled: stripe.Bool(true),
        },
        Metadata: map[string]string{
            "purseId":         transactionInitiation.DestinationId,
            "userId":          transactionInitiation.UserId,
            "transactionId":   transactionId,
            "transactionType": string(transactionInitiation.TransactionType),
        },
    }
    payIntent, _ := sc.PaymentIntents.New(payIntentParams)

    response := struct {
        PaymentIntentClientSecret string `json:"paymentIntent"`
        EphemeralKeySecret        string `json:"ephemeralKey"`
        CustomerID                string `json:"customer"`
        PublishableKey            string `json:"publishableKey"`
    }{
        PaymentIntentClientSecret: payIntent.ClientSecret,
        EphemeralKeySecret:        ephKey.Secret,
        CustomerID:                c.ID,
        PublishableKey:            "pk_test_.....",
    }
    paymentIntentDetails := openapi.PaymentIntentDetails{
        PaymentIntent:  response.PaymentIntentClientSecret,
        EphemeralKey:   response.EphemeralKeySecret,
        Customer:       response.CustomerID,
        PublishableKey: response.PublishableKey,
    }

    return paymentIntentDetails, nil
}
```

Then I am calling this api in my React Native Expo app and feeding it into my payment sheet like this:

```
const initializePaymentSheet = async (paymentIntentDetails : any) => {
    console.log('Initializing payment sheet...');
    try {
        const { error } = await initPaymentSheet({
            merchantDisplayName: "Bityagi, Inc.",
            customerId: paymentIntentDetails.customer,
            customerEphemeralKeySecret: paymentIntentDetails.ephemeralKey,
            paymentIntentClientSecret: paymentIntentDetails.paymentIntent,
            allowsDelayedPaymentMethods: allowsDelayedPaymentMethods,
            defaultBillingDetails: {
                name: 'Jane Doe',
            },
            applePay: {
                merchantCountryCode: 'US',
            },
            googlePay: {
                merchantCountryCode: 'US',
            },
        });
        if (error) throw new Error('Payment sheet initialization failed.');
        return true;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error initializing payment sheet:', error);
        throw error;
    }
};
```

In my App.tsx I have the Stripe component wrapper like this:

```
<StripeProvider
    publishableKey="pk_test_..."
    urlScheme="your-url-scheme"
    merchantIdentifier="merchant.com.patshala"
>
```

There are no issues in the log the problem is after I come to this screen:

[image]

I am redirected to this screen, when I really should just go back to my app, like how it happens with credit card transactions:
[image]

Am I missing something in my settings?

Comment: It could needs more info to debug. I would suggest writing to Stripe Support with an example reproducible projects.